# MikTeX does not detect a package after both online and manual installation (revtex)

Tags: packages, installing, revtex, miktex2.9

I am running MikTeX 2.9.7338 on Windows 10 and trying to compile a document using revtex4-2 in TeXworks 0.6.3.

I followed [these instructions](https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#inst1) and copied the revtex4-2 files in the appropriate TDS folders into my MikTeX 2.9 directory to install the package. However, the compiler fails immediately upon attempting to compile.

The entire contents of the MWE document I am testing on are just

```
\documentclass[
aps,
preprint,
superscriptaddress,
preprintnumbers,
notitlepage,
prb
]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

According to the log, the package isn't installed

```
2020-02-12 14:00:56,597-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.
2020-02-12 14:00:56,597-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: name="revtex"
2020-02-12 14:00:56,597-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageDataStore.cpp
2020-02-12 14:00:56,598-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 394
```

I've also tried installing it from CTAN, and I've tried refreshing the file name database with no success. Other than that, I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone help with this?

Comment: the instruction are behind some login access so it is completly unknown what you did. Why don't you install revtex with the miktex console and its package manager?

Comment: Link fixed, sorry - I didn't notice that a proxy for my university was automatically added to the URL. I did install revtex via the MikTeX console as well, and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that I've also tried installing through MikTeX's connection to CTAN.

Comment: well you did something wrong. I can use revtex4-2 without problems. But your description what you did is much too vage to be able to tell you what you missed. Also your miktex version is quite outdated, a current miktex calls itself "MiKTeX 21.6".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Now I realize that I had 2 versions of MikTeX installed. I've removed both (2.9 and an install from yesterday) and reinstalled MikTeX and no longer have the error with finding revtex. There is another error (`texify - Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.`) which I will see if I can find a solution to. If not I'll put it in a separate question.

Comment: Second error fixed; now everything compiles nicely.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by multiple versions of required files, and the wrong one was being accessed.

Comment: Sounds good to me - I think I just don't have enough points here yet to do so myself, or I would have already.